# I have 3 different constraint layout, and I cannot weigh them properly in my android app

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, constraints

I am creating an app in which I want 3 layouts on the home screen. 1 at the top and 2 at the bottom. It should be in the ratio of 2:3:3 , top:middle:bottom. But for some reason I cannot make them weight properly. Please help.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/quickMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    // some things go in here 

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/topPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quickMenu"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="3">


    // some buttons go in here

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topPanel"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="3">

    //some more buttons go in here.

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The output has to be with the top layout at the top followed by the middle layout followed by the bottom layout. The position of the layouts are correct but i cant seem to get the sizing write in the ratio I want them to be.

Comment: Hmmm... put them in a linear horizontal layout... and Set the total weight of the layout to 3 and then set 1 to the child constraintlayouts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the weight using `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight`, that applies only if the parent is a `ConstraintLayout`. A simple solution to this problem is to use a LinearLayout as the root parent and then set the heights to 0 and the weights accordingly.

You could also have a `ConstraintLayout` as the root and set weights, but I think it's simpler if the root is a `LinearLayout` in this case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/quickMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            // some things go in here

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/topPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3">


            // some buttons go in here

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            //some more buttons go in here.

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: thanks!! its working!!. I was just wondering if using linear layout is a bad practice since constraint layout is the most recent one

Comment: Depends on the layout. ConsttraintLayout is very powerful and flexible, but at times you just need to lay your widgets in a linear fashion like here, so you can use LinearLayout which does a fine job. The same applies to FrameLayout, it has its uses. I would not recommend using RelativeLayout though, it's been superseded by ConstraintLayout.